# How to get the height of elements using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**UPDATE #1:** Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/merianos/bXZ6q/1/)** with all my code.

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul class="topStoriesTab">
    <li data-id="month" class="top_articles">
        <article class="text-center">
            <a href="#post_url" class="topStoriesTitle">Post Title</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#url_here" class="topStoriesAuthor">Author name</a>
            <br>
            <span class="middot text-center topStoriesMidDot">·</span>
        </article>
        ...
    </li>
    <li data-id="year" class="top_articles">
        <article class="text-center">
            <a href="#post_url" class="topStoriesTitle">Post Title</a>
            <br>
            <a href="#url_here" class="topStoriesAuthor">Author name</a>
            <br>
            <span class="middot text-center topStoriesMidDot">·</span>
        </article>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Each `li` in `ul` acts like a tab panel. Outslide this `ul` I have another `ul li` that controls which `li` of this list will appear.

Now what I like to do, is to set the `height` of the `ul` equal to the total height of the `ul li article` elements.

In my code I have try the following:

```
// $tabContent corresponds to the active li element inside the ul.topStoriesTab
$tabContent.find('article').each(
    function(i)
    {
        // Return 0
        console.log($(this).height());

        // Return 0, while in console the samve value is 64
        console.log($(this)[0].clientHeight)

        // Return 0, while in console the samve value is 64
        console.log($(this)[0].offsetHeight)
    }
);
```

Finally I have try all the above methods with the following selector in find, but still no luck:

```
// $tabContent corresponds to the active li element inside the ul.topStoriesTab
$tabContent.find('article *').each(
    function(i)
    {
        // Return 0
        console.log($(this).height());

        // Return 0
        console.log($(this)[0].clientHeight)

        // Return 0
        console.log($(this)[0].offsetHeight)
    }
);
```

So, is there a way to get the height of that elements ?

**UPDATE #1:** Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/merianos/bXZ6q/1/)** with all my code.

As you can see the "Heading" element below the list is comming inside the li, because the UL element seems not have height. This is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Ok I am going to create it now :)

Comment: So, you want the height of each `article`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution was the following:

Instead of this code in my jQuery plugin:

```
function __updatePluginHeight($this, $tabContent)
{
    $total_height   =   0;

    $tabContent.find('article').each(
        function(i)
        {
            console.log($(this)[0].offsetHeight);
        }
    );
}
```

I have modify the code to this:

```
function __updatePluginHeight($this, $tabContent)
{
    console.log($tabContent.height());
}
```

Thanks a lot for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `css` and the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property.

`#wpf_top_articles-2 {overflow:hidden;}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8H7Gn/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't like to hide the overfolowed element. Instead I like to set the height of the .topStoriesTab in order to show all the elements and the heading should be below.

Comment: Currently the .topStoriesTab seems to have height set to 0, this is what I like to overcome.

Comment: oh sweet what was it?

Comment: I have place an answer in my question about the solution. Thanks a lot manta :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('selector').outerHeight()` or `$('selector').innerHeight()` if you are using jquery.

Comment: The title it is not the excact question. If you read question you will see that I am searching for height of a specific element. Anyway, thanks for your assistance

Comment: mate, please replace the `selector` with the id of the element you want the height of.